# SWI-Prolog, odbc_prepare with variable numer of fields in findall-option

Tags: odbc, swi-prolog

The following code runs without problems:

```
prepare_query(QueryFile, Q_Name, Statement) :-
  load_structure(QueryFile, QueryXML, [dialect(xml), space(remove)]),
  getDNS( QueryXML, Q_Name, DNS),
  getSelect(QueryXML, Q_Name, Select),
  getParameter(QueryXML, Q_Name, Parameters),
  => getResultNames(QueryXML, Q_Name, ResultNames),
  odbc_prepare(DNS, Select, Parameters, Statement,
     [ findall((Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b), row(Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b)) ]).
```

The predicate `getResultNames` returns the **atom** `Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b` so I understand why the following code

```
FindAllOption =.. [findall,(ResultNames),row(ResultNames)],
writeln(FindAllOption)
```

returns:

```
findall(Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b,row(Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b))
```

Is it possible to split up `ResultNames` in the separated terms so `FindAllOption` is created as:

```
findall((Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b),row(Apl_id_n, Apl_id_b))
```

Is there another way to make the `findall-option` more flexible?

Ben